# DropDownList Helper to add Null selection without adding a blank item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This code displays a list box with "no" default selection because the default value is hidden.Once the user makes a selection, he cannot set it back to a "no select" state.

Is there a clean way to use an existing MVC helper to build such a list or do I need to write one?

I'm new to MVC and I see various approaches for creating Helper classes. I tend to prefer where everything is done with objects rather than raw string concatenation and I haven't yet figure out a nice approach for handling this case and other special cases, like conditionally enabling/disabling the control, etc, all wrapped up in one nice helper.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select>
  <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think any of the overrides let you specify styling on the blank item.  However, I would avoid doing this if possible -- it's a non-standard user experience and a rather odd use of a select list.

Comment: I feel like a checkbox that sets a dropdown to enabled or disabled might be a better user experience

Comment: @Stephenm: while I admit that it is not common to do this, I think the reason that it is uncommon is more due to it being a browser hack to create missing input control functionality more so than causing a confusing user experience.   I think it works quiet naturally from a UX point of view & that you would have less strong objections if I were to use Javascript to remove the blank selection from the option list after a selection is made. From a UI point of view, the experience would be the same, so it wouldn't be the UX that you object to, it would be the implementation method.

Comment: If you ask me, having a "dummy" item that say "please select" is the epitome of kludges. It's sad that THAT is the standard! That is because the web is young and still sucks and web developers are just too accustomed to it.

Comment: No, it's not your method that I object to, it's the concept.  It's non-standard behavior -- that in and of itself is a reduced user experience.  Further, I think any control should be able to be reset to its initial state.  Finally, this only works when the field is mandatory.  When it is optional it makes no sense to do this, but it also makes no sense to do it some of the time on the site and not the rest of the time.